# Forward a form to a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a form design by `xib` file. In form have a `button` "Done". I want when click done `button`, it will forward to `my view controller`.

I tried code like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
CommentViewController *myVC = (CommentViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Comment"];
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

But error at "presentModelViewController".

```
" No visible @interface for 'my form' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController'...
```

Comment: Please say _what_ the error is.

Comment: Error is " No visible @interface for 'my form' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController'...

Comment: So the problem is that `self` is not a UIViewController. So you can't send `presentModalViewController` to `self`. Send it to a view controller!

Comment: When i try it no error but have a message 'presentModalViewController' is deprecated in IOS 6.0 ??? Running error at main.

Answer (score 1):

If `self` is UINavigationController, use this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

If `self` is UIViewController, use this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Note that: `presentModalViewController: animated:` is deprecated now.

Comment: I call it from a form. My form popup inside my view. That a problem !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self` is not a `UIViewController`. So you can't send `presentModalViewController` to self. Send it to a view controller!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *loStoryboard ;
loStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // Here only "Main" not "Main.storyboard".

// Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
UIViewController *initialViewController = [loStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

// Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
self.view = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
[self.navigationController pushViewController:initialViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answers. But I want to ask you in line 3, what is view ? In my form not have a view, my form is a form have textfield and button. And I call it popup on a view controller !!

Comment: you have to send all items like your textfield & button to your ViewController using NSUSERDEFAULT or initialViewController.text = textfield.text